# optimal way to compare dataframe rows and assign value

Tags: python, pandas

i need to compare previous row value with current row value in data frame if its same need to assign previous row value,i have achived trough  for loop but its taking more time need suggestion for fasted way

```
for y in range(1, len(df_modified_filtered)):
    if df_modified_filtered['Cost Center'].iloc[y - 1] == df_modified_filtered['Cost Center'].iloc[y] :
        df_modified_filtered["costcenter_new"].iloc[y] = df_modified_filtered["costcenter_new"].iloc[y - 1]
```

need optimal solution

Comment: I think this is a job for [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and then comparison operator in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way with the help of shift:

Documentation for shift can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

```
import numpy as np

df_modified_filtered['costcenter_new']=np.where(df_modified_filtered['Cost Center']==df_modified_filtered['Cost Center'].shift(1),df_modified_filtered['costcenter_new'].shift(1),df_modified_filtered['costcenter_new'])
```